# Unable to compile R packages in C for Mac

Tags: r, github, gcc, dplyr

I am requesting some help with my C compiler.  I can't compile R packages from GitHub like `dplyr`.  I can download the package and install it but when I go to load the package with library I get an error message (below).

```
`devtools::install_github("tidyverse/dplyr”)`
```

I receive the error message in a Mac OSX window:
Building R package from source requires installation of additional build tools.
Do you want to install the additional tools now?

I also get this error that makes me think that gcc might not be installed in the correct place:

```
￼￼checking for gcc... /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.2.0/bin/gcc-7
checking whether the C compiler works... no
```

So far I have tried to check my compiler.

```
gcc -v
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

I successfully reinstalled Xcode for build tools directly from the Apple Development site and from the command line.

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
xcode-select --install
```

I checked my .bash_profile as I thought that might be the issue:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
#export PATH=/usr/local/clang8/bin:$PATH

PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

Thank you in advance,
Tyler